# Xcode 7.3 update through App Store not working

Tags: xcode

I realise that there are a few questions/answers and I also realise that I can download via the developer page, however it says 7.3 is installed ...

[image]

but when you start Xcode it is still the previous version.

Is there a work around or do you have to download a fresh copy? With a very slow connection I would rather avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly you are going to have to download a fresh copy of Xcode. Same thing happened to me and I tried everything. Restarting my computer, closing it in Force quit applications and tons more and nothing worked. Fresh install would be the only option for you.

Comment: I suffer from slow internet too so when I found that it I was pretty upset! Took me 17...

Answer (score 0):

Check that you don't have any backup drives/clones/time machines etc connected, and that you only have the one MAS Xcode version installed (you can check if it's a MAS version by going to /Applications or wherever, and opening the Xcode folder with `Show Package Contents`, then looking in the `Contents` folder for a `_MASReceipt` folder. If that's there, it's a MAS version).

The MAS app has an issue where it will update the app on backup drives etc that are connected to your machine when you do the update, often before it updates the version you expect it to update (in /Applications). This could mean it may need to do a few updates before it gets to the one you're actually using.

If you like to keep old versions of Xcode around, always delete the `_MASReceipt` folder from the old ones. That will prevent the MAS app from upgrading them later.

[image: _MASReceipt]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I can't find a _MASReceipt.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of what the `_MASReceipt` structure should look like. If you don't have this in the folder, it's not considered a MAS managed version of Xcode and the MAS app will never update it.

Comment: That is really interesting. I am certain that I have always updated Xcode in this way though, ever since I first installed it years ago.

Comment: It's possible you deleted it. If the MAS app is telling you it's updated Xcode to 7.3, then it sees a version with a receipt somewhere. Check Time Machine maybe?